# Error on rendering mathematical symbol - getting source file of rfxlri-alt from newtx package

Tags: miktex, newtx

I'm running a miktex installation on an airgapped computer and have been installing latex packages manually. I've installed the newtx fonts but miktex is giving the following error:

```
INFO miktex-makemf - starting with commmand line: "[...] \x64\miktex-makemf.exe" -- verbose rfxlri-alt
FATAL miktex-makemf - The rfxlri-alt source file could not be found.
```

Additionally, looking at miktex-makepk.log:

```
INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makepk.exe" --verbose rfxlri-alt 600 600 magstep(0.0)
INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font rfxlri-alt at 600 DPI...
INFO  makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
INFO  makepk - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
INFO  makepk - running: miktex-makemf.exe --verbose rfxlri-alt
INFO  makepk - Running miktex-ttf2pk.exe...
INFO  makepk - running: miktex-ttf2pk.exe -q -t rfxlri-alt
FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font rfxlri-alt could not be created.
```

I've checked that newtx has been installed. I've Refreshed FNDB. It appears to be looking for the source file of rfxlri-alt, but font/source doesn't contain this and the packages I can find don't have a copy: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newtx

hacking at the file, the error only occurs when there is a mathematical symbol in the text, such as

```
$>$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran updmap from the command line and this error disappeared